# Swagger Spring-MVC description parameter not honored from @Api annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I'm trying to use swagger spring-mvc (https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc) to auto-generate documentation for my java spring MVC API.

Why is the description not being used from my @Api annotation? I'm using (com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api). Here's my @Api declaration in my controller:

```
@Api(value = "hierarchies", description = "Hierarchies Resource")
```

and here's the resultant JSON from /api-docs/ :

```
{"path":"/v1/hierarchies","description":"hierarchies"}
```

Even the swagger online demo shows the description working:

http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/

in the JSON, it shows:
{"path":"/pet","description":"Operations about pets"}

It seems as though the documentation engine is ignoring the description field, no matter what I enter, and simply uses the value for the description. Am I doing something wrong in swagger-springmvc? Do I need to use a different annotation? Is this just a bug in swagger-spring-mvc?

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry for dummy question. Did you rebuild project? If so please post your swagger configuration.